# get form responses to write at the top of a google sheet after clearing the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a less than primitive script writer and am having a bit a problem. The situation is I have staff providing feedback in the way of a form daily which then populates a spreadsheet for the following day. I have a script that is clearing the form every night however the next day when they fill out the form their answers go somewhat down the page. For example, if there have been 62 forms filled out since the inception of this form, it writes their answers starting at row 63.

What I want is to clear the page at night and then when they answer the form the following day their answers appear at the top of the sheet.

The script I currently use is as follows.

`function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  sheet.getRange('A2:AN99').clearContent();}`

Any suggestions on an addition to this script that will help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is you are clearing the content rather than deleting the range. Try:    '. deleteCells'